# WCM IO testing sling mappings

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

I am trying to test my sling mappings in WCM IO but it seems that they are not getting picked up: This is how I am loading my mappings:

```
context.load().json("/sample-content/sling-mappings/etc-map.json", "/etc/map");
```

etc-map.json:

```
{
  "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Folder",
  "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
  "hidden": "true",
  "http": {
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Folder",
    "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
    "mysite_be": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
      "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
      "sling:match": "mysite.be/nl/(.+)$",
      "sling:internalRedirect": [
        "/content/mysite/nl/$1"
      ],
      "redirect": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
        "jcr:createdBy": "admin",
        "sling:match": "(.+)$",
        "sling:internalRedirect": [
          "/content/mysite/nl/$1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Debugging the `map` method on the resourceResolver:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: In my up and running AEM environment the mappings do work when I try them out under `.../system/console/jcrresolver`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the ResourceResolverMock doesn't implement a real resource mapping.

https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=sling-org-apache-sling-testing-resourceresolver-mock.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/sling/testing/resourceresolver/MockResourceResolver.java;hb=HEAD

Feel free to contribute. But to be honest, I also never did (shame on me).